# Firefox blocks my nvidia drivers MOZ_GLX_IGNORE_BLACKLIST

Tags: firefox, nvidia, webgl

When I load a WebGL website on Firefox 5 in my Ubuntu 11.04 system, I get a grey screen and a warning on the terminal like this:

```
[GLX] your GL driver is currently blocked. If you would like to bypass this, define the MOZ_GLX_IGNORE_BLACKLIST environment variable.
```

Acceleration works fine on Google Chrome. How can I enable back acceleration for Firefox?

Comment: Not all Nvidia cards support hardware acceleration, perhaps this is why you get the warning. How many Nvidia driver do you have installed and what are they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why the driver is on the blacklist, but you can do what's suggested: try running `MOZ_GLX_IGNORE_BLACKLIST=1 firefox`.

If this works, you can modify the .desktop file `/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop` and change the line

```
Exec=firefox %u`
```

to

```
Exec=env MOZ_GLX_IGNORE_BLACKLIST=1 firefox %u
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed the proprietary drivers or are you using the default ones that come with Ubuntu. Nouveau for what I know does not support the requirements for WebGL... yet. But if you install for the time being the nvidia Proprietary ones you will get full support. If i may ask, what video card are you using. You only need one that support OpenGL ES 2.0. Test here: http://doesmybrowsersupportwebgl.com/ to see what support you have and if you can install the proprietary ones if not yet installed.

Comment: i've got the nvidia proprietary drivers installed. google-chrome on the website shows a YAY, Firefox shows a NAY

Comment: Are you SURE you have Firefox 5. Go to Help -> About in Firefox because right now am writing this on Firefox 5.0. Make sure is not some Beta/Alpha/Omega something. It should say only 5.0 in the version number.